# Getting file path from user input in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the file path from user input. i have used the below syntax

```
import pandas as pd


path = input("Enter the path of your file:")
sheetname = input("Enter the sheet name:")

path_1 = ("r'"+path+"'")

df1 = pd.read_excel(path_1, sheet_name = sheetname)
```

but am getting "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"  error

Could someone help me out to get it done

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. You must've entered a bogus file path.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a "raw string literal" with `path_1 = ("r'"+path+"'")`, but this only ends up creating a string like "r'foo'", which is not a valid path. I guess you're not even using `path_1` in `read_excel` so maybe you should just remove this from your code snippet?

Comment: The strings you type into `input()` are escaped anyways.  If you enter `\n\n`, you get `"\\n\\n"`, not two newlines.

Comment: @rkersh I have corrected the syntax, though am getting the same error. Is there anyother way to get it done?

Comment: @Cybertron: I don't think you understood my comment. The way you construct `path_1` is incorrect. You should revert your edit and go back to the way it was (i.e., just use `path` in `read_excel`). Can you show us the path and sheetname you are entering at the command line when you run this program?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some issues on the input. For example if your system expects forward-slashes and you give it back-slashes, or if your input doesn't include the file extension, it'll throw an error.

Also, looking at the docs for `pandas.read_excel`, it looks like the `sheet_name` is actually a sheet within the file itself. If you're putting only the folder as the `path` and the filename as the `sheet_name`, that would cause an error as well. Not sure if that's what you're doing, but I'm pretty sure that's what I would have done :)